# jQuery - "$ symbol is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was successfully using some plugin for about 6 months on my website and all of a sudden I started getting this message for one of my scripts: "$ is undefined".

This is the problematic line of code: `$.widget("ui.ImageColorPicker", uiImageColorPicker);`

I'm using this plugin and almost the newest jQuery with noConflict enabled: http://github.com/Skarabaeus/ImageColorPicker I didn't change anything for 6 months (I didn't update jQuery). I'm sure it worked fine just 2 weeks ago and now it's broken all of a sudden.

EDIT: Error is gone. I'm removing example website.

Comment: Of course, jQuery is included and the script works partially. Actually only "click" event from that script stopped working.

Comment: Is that the only error in the console?

Comment: In order to use jQuery.widget, you may need to include a jQuery plugin - perhaps jQuery UI?

Comment: *Something* changed if it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: jQuery UI - didn't help. I think nothing has changed since then. Maybe external scripts got updates (like YouTube API script that we include) but we didn't change anything in our code.

Comment: whats the sequence of scripts you added on your page...

Comment: @Wasim Karani You can check that page. I provided URL.

Comment: Where exactly do you load jQuery? I mean standard jQuery, not jQueryUI. I can't see it in network tab in Chrome Inspector

Comment: jQuery is there. In <head> section. Many jQuery scripts work fine and colorpickers works partially fine, too. First script tag loads it.

Comment: That load script doesn't seem to be working. For me it's not pulling down jQuery at all...

Comment: @Phill - it obviously loads jQuery. Many things in WordPress admin panel use jQuery successfully right now. Even my jQuery-based custom scripts work. Only colorpicker doesn't work (partially!)

Comment: You had 2 problems: first was solved by @beeglebug's answer, and second is that you load jQueryUI and jQuery.ImageColorPicker in parallel, and sometimes you end up trying to initialize colorpicker before you have jQueryUI (which ColorPicker depends on)

Comment: To test it, open Net tab in Chrome Inspector or Firefox, reload page and check loading bars of your scripts.

Comment: @MBO Finally, the error is gone! I did what you said + added noConflict and the error is gone! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a variable scope issue.

Try changing the first line to this:

```
(function($){
```

and the last line to this:

```
})(jQuery);
```

By doing this we are passing in the `jQuery` object to the anonymous function which surrounds the plugin, but by referencing it as `$` the code within the block can be written using 'normal' jQuery, while still maintaining the noConflict mode on the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. That didn't help. I already tried all solutions like that before :) It says: $.widget is not a function

Comment: I did that along with re-ordering jQuery UI to load earlier and it works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script> //In your case try Imagecolorpicker js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) $.noConflict();

Comment: shouldn't the order be to include jquery, call noConflict, include other library?

Comment: I was already using noConflict and with or without it (despite of place I include it), it doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the explicit `jQuery` object instead of it's `$` alias.
For instance:

```
jQuery.widget("ui.ImageColorPicker", uiImageColorPicker);
```

Comment: Didn't help :( Now it says: "jQuery.widget is not a function"

Comment: You can't use the dollar sign for jQuery with noConflict enabled, so this answer is at least partially correct.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `jQuery.Widget` is defined on that page.  Try that instead of `$.widget`.

Comment: It is $.widget now. I tried jQuery.widget for a few seconds and now $.widget is restored.

Comment: Try it with a capital 'W'.  JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: Was what you tried exactly `jQuery.Widget`?  Because I typed that in the console, and that function does exist on that page.

Comment: By the way, some other jQuery plugins I've seen use `$` as a parameter to their wrapper function, then pass `jQuery` as the value for that parameter - that allows them to use dollar sign syntax even when noConflict is enabled.  You might want to do the same.

Comment: Yes, both $ and jQuery work successfully for other modules on the same website. That's the only broken file. Yes, I used exactly jQuery.Widget but it didn't change anything. Only error changed.

Comment: Getting a different error is relevant.  I think I know what the new error is, though - "(the function) has no method '_createWidget'".  Which is true, and the fact that jQuery is expecting that method suggests to me that jQuery UI has been updated to a version that isn't compatible with your plugin.

Comment: @Brilliand The plugin in question hasn't been updated in over a year according to github, so that seems likely.

Comment: I've found an object that has a `widget` function (lowercase).  Or at least, I've detected that one exists.  I can't seem to work out where it's coming from.  Chrome's console is not being very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you included jQuery UI.  try to use `jQuery.widget`. If that doesn't work, use:

`e = jQuery; // you can use anything else than $`

Now, you should type `e.widget("ui.ImageColorPicker", uiImageColorPicker);`
instead of what you have.